# How do I get the output of iostat as a graph in Solaris 9

Tags: solaris, iostat

Is there a built-in/custom script available?

Answer (score 1):

In fact not really programming related.  Anyway, from my experience, [munin](http://opencsw.wikidot.com/munin-package) can generate very nice graphs, powered by rrdtool.  You can also host a munin master on a different machine and collect data from many munin nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Although its maybe not really programing related you could try [Orca](http://www.orcaware.com/orca/).

Answer (score 0):

[dim_STAT](http://dimitrik.free.fr/) is really nice.